# How to expand a table into multiple columns with a query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

To answer my question, I will simplify my data structure.  I have three tables, Sample, Analysis, Values.  Sample has a Pk autonumber field, SampleID, and a DateCreated field.  Analysis has a PK autonumber field AnalysisID, and a AnalysisName field.  Values has three fields, SampleID, AnalysisID, Value.  A generic layout of the data is below.

Sample

```
 SampleID     DateCreated
 1            6/1/2013
 2            6/2/2013
 3            6/3/2013
 4            6/3/2013
```

Analysis

```
AnalysisID    AnalysisName
1             Temp
2             Density
3             Mass
```

Values

```
SampleID    AnalysisID    Value
1           1             65
1           2             1.1
2           1             68
2           2             1.0
2           3             57
3           2             1.2
4           2             0.9
4           3             54
```

Now, I want someone to be able to design a query on the fly... and I think I can figure that out, IF I can figure out how to get this data into the following format.  For instance, if the user wanted all samples and analysis, the query needs to generate a table like this...

```
SampleID  DateCreated  Temp  Denisty  Mass
1         6/1/2013     65    1.1 
2         6/2/2013     68    1.0      57
3         6/3/2013           1.2
4         6/3/2013           0.9      54
```

What will the query look like to get this result?  I can figure out how to create it on the fly with VBA, as long as I can understand what the end SQL result needs to look like.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a PIVOT table query that will do it for you.
The tables 1-3 are in the order you listed them. I also renamed Value to Value1 because its a reserved word.

```
TRANSFORM First(Table3.Value1) AS FirstOfValue1
SELECT Table1.SampleID, Table1.DateCreated
FROM Table2 INNER JOIN (Table1 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.SampleID = Table3.SampleID) ON Table2.AnalysisID = Table3.AnalysisID
GROUP BY Table1.SampleID, Table1.DateCreated
PIVOT Table2.AnalysisName;
```

Paste this into the SQL part of your query builder, then click the design button to see how it's done.

Comment: I like this method, it is quick and easy!  However, I am not sure how I could modify it to only show certain ones.  Like, if I only wanted Temp and Density, how would I prevent Mass from showing up?  Using a WHERE clause to say WHERE AnalysisID = 1 OR AnalysisID = 2?  And, can I specify an order, rather than alphabetical?  People are used to seeing them in a certain order and changing it may be difficult to adapt.  Thanks so much, I have never really messed with PIVOT tables before, I can see how they could be very handy.

Comment: Exactly, add WHERE criteria to the subquery.

Comment: Thanks!  Any help on organizing the fields based on AnalysisID rather than AnalysisName?  They are showing up left-to-right alphabetically, rather than numerically.  I want Temp in the 3rd column, Density 4th, and Mass 5th.

Comment: What happens when you ORDER BY Analysis ID?  After GROUP BY, before PIVOT, just spit-balling here.

Comment: It was an interesting question, so I spent some time looking for an answer. Looks like the only way to do it is by adding in("Temp","Density","Mass",...) on the end of the PIVOT statement. I'd just make a query on the fly with VBA to include this info.

Comment: Got it!  I added 'in' and that worked!  Like this... `PIVOT Analysis.AnalysisName in ("Temp","Density","Mass")`  This will be easy to generate on the fly and will allow me to export perfectly!  Thanks!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your welcome. Seems like there should be something built in, but it's Microsoft, so what are you going to do? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about Access-specific answer, but you can probably use CASE statements, simplified without all your joins, something like:

```
SELECT SampleID, DateCreated
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN AnalysisID = 1 THEN Value ELSE '' END) as Temp
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN AnalysisID = 2 THEN Value ELSE '' END) as Density
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN AnalysisID = 3 THEN Value ELSE '' END) as Mass
FROM Tables/Joins, Etc.
GROUP BY SampleID, DateCreated
```

You could also look into PIVOT function, but if you have only a handful of Analysis types then this is a simple way to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion.  I currently have 53 analysis types with 125,000 rows in the values tables.  I have never used a setup like this, but an up for giving it a try...  does it seem likely to work for so many rows?  I am going to estimate we will have 300,000+ rows in values each year.

Comment: Well, it might be cumbersome to make 53 MAX/CASE statements, but it will work just fine.

Comment: So 'CASE WHEN' is T-SQL, Access does not support it, but I have got SWITCH to work halfway.  I can get the values, but they are not grouped by SampleID, and if I include this, I have to include all the 'SWITCH' elements as part of an aggregate.  I don't know how to do this and keep the data integrity.

Comment: Sounds like PIVOT might be the way to go in Access then.